# CSS is not loading for antd Menu option

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

In react with next.js framework I'm using antd npm packge for controls like table ,menu etc.But css is not loading for the controls .What I'm doing wrong..

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
 import '../Header/header.css';
 class HeaderComponent extends Component {
     render() {
         return (
             <div className="navbar">
                 <div className="col-1">
                     <img src="../../static/logo.png" ></img>
                 </div>
                 <div className="col-2">
                     <Menu mode="horizontal">
                         <Menu.Item key="app-user">App Users</Menu.Item>
                         <Menu.Item key="non-app-user">Non App Users</Menu.Item>
                     </Menu>
                 </div>
             </div>        );
     }
 }
```

Edit:
css header.css

```
 .navbar {
     width: 100%;

 }

 .header {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
```

this is My next.config.js

```
 if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
     require.extensions['.less'] = file => {};

   }

   const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less'),
      nextConfig = {
       //target: 'serverless',
       env: {
         weatherApi: '',
         mapBoxApi: ''
       },
       onDemandEntries: {
         maxInactiveAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
         pagesBufferLength: 5
       },
       lessLoaderOptions: {
         javascriptEnabled: true
       },
       webpack: config => config
     };

   module.exports = withLess(nextConfig);
```

I think I have to make configuration in nextconfig.js.generates this error

Error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Comment: Did you import css in your application? if you are using any build tool make sure yo include css while bundling. or you can use `import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; // or 'antd/dist/antd.less'
 `. please go through the doc on antD about how to import css: https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the css in your main css file say app.css

app.css:

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

.App {
  some css...;
}
```

...

and then import app.css in your parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
import './app.css';
 class HeaderComponent extends Component {
     render() {
         return (
             <div className="navbar">
                 <div className="col-1">
                     <img src="../../static/logo.png" ></img>
                 </div>
                 <div className="col-2">
                     <Menu mode="horizontal">
                         <Menu.Item key="app-user">App Users</Menu.Item>
                         <Menu.Item key="non-app-user">Non App Users</Menu.Item>
                     </Menu>
                 </div>
             </div>        );
     }
 }
```

**or** import `import "antd/dist/antd.css"` instead of including in seperate css file.

Comment: But the css that I have wrote is not loading for simple div

Comment: can you add that piece of code, so that I can have better understanding.

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css : do something like this `// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true
})`